# ERROR:ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join, group-by

```
select frstname,addr  
from medication,patient  
where medication.patientnum=patient.ptnum  
group by frstname,addr  
having finish_date='29-01-20';
```

how do i solve this error?

Comment: With an error like that I doubt this is correctky tagged (MySQL)

Comment: You shoudl also look into the JOIN syntax rather than using `from medication,patient`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very unclear what the purpose of your query is.

An immediate fix is to move the condition form the `having` clause to the `where` clause, because the column it uses is not part of the `group by` clause - and to use proper join syntax and date litterals:

```
select frstname, addr  
from medication m
inner join patient p on m.patientnum = p.ptnum  
where finish_date = date '2020-01-29'
group by frstname, addr
```

I would also warmly recommend prefixing each column with the table it belongs to, using the table aliases that I added to the query (`m` for `medication`, `p` for `patient`).

This might, or might not, do what you actually intend. If not, then you should probably ask a new question, providing sample data, expected results, and an explanation of what you are trying to accomplish.